# Unban repeated attempts via command or mysql?

Tags: users

Natively, in Drupal 7 after repeated unsuccessful attempts a particular user would be banned after repeated offending logins.

Is it possible to programmatically unban a particular user? I heard if you truncate the flood table you can be unbanned. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true, but it is also excessive.

That table is also used for users sending emails with the contact form. Rather than truncating that table, it is better to remove only the necessary entries.
[user_login_final_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7) contains the following code.

```
  if (empty($form_state['uid'])) {
    // Always register an IP-based failed login event.
    flood_register_event('failed_login_attempt_ip', variable_get('user_failed_login_ip_window', 3600));
    // Register a per-user failed login event.
    if (isset($form_state['flood_control_user_identifier'])) {
      flood_register_event('failed_login_attempt_user', variable_get('user_failed_login_user_window', 21600), $form_state['flood_control_user_identifier']);
    }
```

Just remove any row in the "flood" table where the "event" field is equal to "failed_login_attempt_ip" or "failed_login_attempt_user"; in that way, any login ban is removed.
This would remove the login ban for every user, including the ones who are trying to access somebody else's account by brute force. Unfortunately, without to know the IP of the user to unblock, it is not possible to unblock just a specific user: The login validation callbacks first check if the user is login banned basing on the IP, then basing on the user ID for the account used to login.

Answer (score 0):

The [Flood Unblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock) module provides both a UI and a `drush` command to remove bans from excessive failed logins of a particular type:

- `ip` for IP address bans due to wrong usernames
- `user` for IP address bans due to wrong passwords
- `all` for both these types of bans

So while it is not possible with this module to unban a particular user, you can remove all bans resulting from failed logins (as recommended in the [other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/52195/16305)) like this:

```
drush flood_unblock all
```

Answer (score 0):

When you *do* know the IP address of the user you want to unblock, for example by [letting them google it](https://www.google.de/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip), you can unban that user with a SQL query like this:

```
drush sql-query "DELETE FROM flood WHERE 
    event LIKE 'failed_login_attempt_%' AND 
    identifier LIKE '%189.67.116.250'"
```