# How to unblock IPs in bulk?

Tags: 7, users

I use the Drupal Core IP blocking feature (`/admin/config/people/ip-blocking`) to block IP addresses during spam attacks. However, as most of these will be dynamic ones owned by legitimate users a day later, I want to remove these blocks.

I could delete them one by one in the IP blocking interface, but with dozens of addresses, that is not a comfortable way. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, choose depending on your requirements:

- You can use module [Blocked IPs Expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/blocked_ips_expire) to add an expiration date to IP blocks when adding them. The Drupal cron job will remove the blockings after expiry.
- You can remove all of the IP blockings at once with this [`drush`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/) command:

  ```
  drush sql-query "TRUNCATE TABLE blocked_ips"
  ```
- You can remove just some IP blockings (e.g. an IP range) with similar `drush` commands. For example to delete all IPv4 blocks:

  ```
  drush sql-query "DELETE FROM blocked_ips WHERE ip LIKE '%.%.%.%'"
  ```

Note that auto-banning users and IP addresses after a number of unsuccessful login attempts is a different Drupal Core mechanism, resulting in entries in table `flood` – [more details](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/52195/16305). To remove these bans, the [Flood Unblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock) module can help you. (But that mechanism is out of the scope of this question anyway.)

Comment: For Drupal 8+ see this Drush feature request: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/5348